# How can overwrite this calculation?JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this site:

[link](http://bagel.dg-site.com/bagel/index.php/contact/)

I have two pages that contain the same divs... on a page I want to be a calculation (to div) on another page another calculation..,

**CODE JS:(NEW)**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    var windowsizecontact = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
    console.log("ecran contact:",windowsizecontact);
    var stanga= jQuery('.contact-stanga').outerWidth();
    console.log("latime-stanga:",stanga);  
    var dreapta= jQuery('.contact-dreapta').outerWidth();  
    console.log("latime-dreapta:",dreapta);  
    var contentcontactwh=windowsizecontact-stanga-dreapta;
    console.log("rezultat",contentcontactwh);
    $('.contact-container #primary').css{('cssText', contentcontactwh'!important')};   //here I want to overide this div

});
```

This is old code (which must remain and apply only on certain pages)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var latime= Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
    var _stanga= jQuery('#secondary').outerWidth();
    var selectat= jQuery('.selectat').outerWidth();
    var calcul=latime-_stanga-selectat;
    $('#primary').css('width', calcul);

});
```

My problem is that the new code (from above) does not apply to div on the contact page because old code ... and I need to do to be unique. (Old code should remain as )

It can override somehow?

EDIT:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  var windowsizecontact = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
  console.log("ecran contact:",windowsizecontact);
  var stanga= jQuery('.contact-stanga').outerWidth();
  console.log("latime-stanga:",stanga);  
  var dreapta= jQuery('.contact-dreapta').outerWidth();  
  console.log("latime-dreapta:",dreapta);  
  var contentcontactwh=windowsizecontact-stanga-dreapta;
  console.log("rezultat",contentcontactwh);
  console.log("------------------");



  if ($("#primary").hasClass("content-contact")) {
     alert("ggg");
      $('.content-contact').css("width:",contentcontactwh); //here now is problem

  }else
  {
  var latime= Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
  var _stanga= jQuery('#secondary').outerWidth();
  console.log("latime-stanga:",_stanga);
  var selectat= jQuery('.selectat').outerWidth();
  console.log("latime-stanga:",_stanga); 
  var calcul=latime-_stanga-selectat;
  $('#primary').css('width', calcul);
   }

});
```

I tried the first option suggested ... but now not only apply div width of my.

I've done wrong syntax?

Comment: Try to use something to understand in which page you are currently and call the function accordingly instead of calling it immediately after document ready.

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

if(contact)
{
    new_function();
}
else
{
    old_function();
}

Comment: I tried your solution ... you can look less at the code? I edited the post

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = app || {};

app.readyFunction = function () {
    // normal
};

// on website you want to overwrite
app.readyFunction = function () {
    // altCode
};

// and in document ready just call
$(function () {
    app.readyFunction();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If al the rest works and if the problem is only in this line then lets change this line a bit.

this

```
  $('.content-contact').css("width:",contentcontactwh); //try removing the : after width
```

to

```
  $('.content-contact').css("width",contentcontactwh);
```

Also please provide the console error message if this does not work.